# Can I pass an SQL query to sql server encoded in hex or decimal?

Tags: sql-server, database

I am having some problems with collation in sql server, and I am wondering if I can "pass" the sql query to the server encoded in some 'universal' way? That is, instead of writing:

```
select * from table; -- ASCII
```

I want to write something like:

```
char(39)char(32)char(3222) -- DECIMAL VALUES
```

Is there some way that sql server will automatically detect decimal or hex language and convert it on the fly to an ascii sql query and then automatically execute it?

Comment: You're better off explaining what your collation problem is, your question doesn't make much sens.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this ([as seen in SQL injection attacks](http://www.bloombit.com/Articles/2008/05/ASCII-Encoded-Binary-String-Automated-SQL-Injection.aspx)).

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(4000)
SET @S=CAST(0x53454C454354202A2046524F4D207379732E6F626A65637473 AS VARCHAR(4000))
EXEC(@S)
```

I cannot envisage any scenario where this would be required though.